# Why does istream_iterator<string>(ifstream("test.txt")) cause an error?

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream, istream-iterator

I have tried to write a code to read strings from file named "test.txt" and write the strings to standard output. The code below works well:

```
 int main()
 {
     using namespace std;
     ifstream file("test.txt");
     copy(istream_iterator<string>(file), 
          istream_iterator<string>(), 
          ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " ")); 
 }
```

However, with this modification, the code no longer compiles:

```
   int main()
   {
        using namespace std;
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(ifstream("test.txt")),  // <-- Error here
        istream_iterator<string>(), 
        ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));   
   }
```

Why doesn't this version compile?

The compiler I used is g++4.6.2, and the error as below:

```
ex11-16.cpp:16:65: error: no matching function for call to 'std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >::istream_iterator(std::ifstream)'
ex11-16.cpp:16:65: note: candidates are:
.../bits/stream_iterator.h:72:7: note: std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_iterator(const std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Dist = int, std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist> = std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >]
.../bits/stream_iterator.h:72:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' to 'const std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >&'
.../bits/stream_iterator.h:68:7: note: std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_iterator(std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_type&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Dist = int, std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
.../bits/stream_iterator.h:68:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' to 'std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >::istream_type& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}'
.../bits/stream_iterator.h:64:26: note: std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_iterator() [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Dist = int]
.../bits/stream_iterator.h:64:26: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: *can even not be compiled* - That warrants at least giving us the error.

Comment: In the second example `ifstream(test.txt)` should be `ifstream("test.txt")` or you should edit your question to include the correct code.

Answer (score 8):

There are (I believe) two errors here:

(1) You need to put quotations around `test.txt`:

```
istream_iterator<string>(ifstream("test.txt"), ... );
```

(2) `istream_iterator`'s constructor takes in an `istream&` (that is, an lvalue reference to a stream).  Consequently, the stream that you pass in has to be an lvalue.  However, passing in `ifstream("test.txt")` passes in a temporary object of type `ifstream`, which is an *rvalue* rather than an *lvalue*.  This is the same reason that you can't do this:

```
int function(int& x) {
    x++;
}
int main() {
    function(137); // Error - 137 is an rvalue, but lvalue is needed.
}
```

Hope this helps!